# Express.js - how to download base64 string as PDF file?

Tags: node.js, file, express, stream, base64

I have pdf file encoded as base64 string. How to download this string to the browser as file in .pdf format?

What I have already tried:

```
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

res.write(fileBase64String, 'base64');
```

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of extra streams, why not just do `res.write(fileBase64String, 'base64')` ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, updated the question :) I can see the response status OK on the client side, but file is never being saved.

Comment: If that's all you are writing, use `res.end(fileBase64String, 'base64')`, which will both write the data and close the response.

Answer (score 20):

I ended up to decode the pdf first and then send it to the browser as binary as follows:

*(For simplicity I use `node-http` here but the functions are available in `express` as well)*

```
const http = require('http');

http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    getEncodedPDF(function(encodedPDF) {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.pdf"'
      });

      const download = Buffer.from(encodedPDF.toString('utf-8'), 'base64');

      res.end(download);
    });
  })
  .listen(1337);
```

---

What drove me nuts here was the testing with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/):
I was using the <kbd>Send</kbd> Button instead of the <kbd>Send and Download</kbd> [Button](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/832#issuecomment-229925026) to submit the request:[image]

Using the <kbd>Send</kbd> button for this request causes that the pdf file becomes corrupted after saving.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference for `Express`. This answer is based on ofhouse's answer.

This solution is downloading a png file. I was missing the "Content-Disposition" part, which makes the browser not display the png, but download it. `png` is a `Buffer`-object.

```
app.get("/image", (req, res) => {
    getPng()
      .then((png) => {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": png.ContentType,
          "Content-Length": png.ContentLength,
          "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="image.png"',
        });
        res.end(png.Body);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        res.send("Couldn't load the image.");
      });
});
```